# Show/hide one of the dynamically created elements

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I have a simple problem that I can't solve. Having multiple elements dynamically created (see picture attached), I need to show/hide the dropdown content only for the element I clicked on.
The code bellow is showing/hiding all the elements by pressing any of the buttons.

[image: dropdown content is hidden]

[image: dropdown content is shown]

I can get the index of the for loop by **{{ loop.index }}** and use it to dynamically create an id for every dropdown or pass it as a parameter, but still have issues to use it and manipulate the dropdown content to show or hide.

**toggleDropdown()** is setting the **isVisible** variable to true or false and based on the value the dropdown is displayed or not.

Here is my **controller:**

```
OffersCtrl.$inject = ['PROFILE_ID', '$location'];

function OffersCtrl(PROFILE_ID, $location) {
  let vm = this;

  vm.isVisible = false;
  vm.getText = getText;
  vm.toggleDropdown = toggleDropdown;

  function toggleDropdown() {
    vm.isVisible = !vm.isVisible;
  }
}
```

this is my `html/twig` (`OffersCtrl`  is defined as `$ctrl`):

```
<ul class="offer-tiles">
    {% for offer in profile.offers %}
    <li>
        <div class="content">
            <p class="title">{{ offer.title }}</p>

            <p class="price">
                <span class="symbol">€</span>
                <span class="value">{{ offer.price.convertedAmount }}</span>
            </p>

            <p class="description">{{ offer.category.name }}</p>

            <input type="button" id="expandBtn" class="expand" value="v" ng-click="$ctrl.toggleDropdown()" />
        </div>
        <div class="box-dropdown" ng-show="$ctrl.isVisible">
            <p>{{ offer.description }}</p>
            <hr/>
            .... 
        </div>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `isVisible` as an array, because you have multiple values.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function() {
    const vm = this;

    vm.isVisible = [];
    vm.toggleDropdown = toggleDropdown;
    vm.offers = [
      {description: 'lorem'},
      {description: 'ipsum'},
      {description: 'dolor'},
      {description: 'sit'},
      {description: 'amet'},
    ]

    function toggleDropdown(index) {
      vm.isVisible[index] = !vm.isVisible[index];
    }
  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
  <ul class="offer-tiles">
    <li ng-repeat="offer in vm.offers track by $index">
        <!-- ... -->
        <input type="button" value="v" ng-click="vm.toggleDropdown($index)" />
        <div class="box-dropdown" ng-show="vm.isVisible[$index]">
            <p>{{ offer.description }}</p>
            <hr />
            ...
        </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! All I needed was the idea of using isVisible as array, that solved the problem with only few changes.